# Lerna: how can i get successfully published packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lerna

I'm having monorepo with lerna and demo web-site.
I want to publish changed packages and automatically update it in demo from 1 command like `npm run release`.
**package.json:**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "release": "node ./release.js",
  ...
}
```

**release.js**

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const cmd = `npx lerna publish`;
const updatedPackages = spawnSync(cmd, { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true }); // there i want get list of successfully published packages.

udpdateDemo(updatedPackages); // custom function, which get list of packages and update it for demo
```